# Special local characters in a unit test isn't the same everywhere

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, unit-testing, localization, utf-8

In a unit test I have this:

```
LastName = "Näs"
```

This is later encoded so I want to make sure that it is correct. Works fine for me on my configuration (swedish regional settings).
But Yuriy who sits in Ukraine with Ukrainian settings don't see this. Instead he sees this:

```
LastName = "Nдs"
```

This makes the unit test fail... :(

It should be utf-8, so why doesn't he see the same character..?

Comment: You say "It should be utf-8" but have you verified this?  Examine the byte stream of the test file.  A UTF-8 character in this case will be two bytes long.  Sounds like you're actually in another encoding (probably a single byte encoding) hence the different decoding.

Comment: Is this in a source file, or a text file that your test reads in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how Visual Studio is reading the file... if it's opening it and assuming some other encoding, that will cause a problem. You need to *either* make sure everyone has the same settings, standardizing on UTF-8, *or* use the `\uxxxx escape` for any non-ASCII characters in your source code.

Standardizing is more error-prone but the code ends up being easier to read; `\uxxxx` is robust but a pain from a readability standpoint :(